# Error while my program parse an xml file "java.lang.NumberFormatException"

Tags: java, xml

Hello everyone i have a problem i have an huge xml file that my program parse

The file is like that

> node id="2153071645"
>
> node id="2153071646"
>
> node id="2153238985"
>
> node id="2153238987"
>
> node id="2153240107"
>
> node id="2153240112"

And after, reading many tag correctly the following error appear .

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2151726861"
>      at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
>      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>      at SimpleContentHandler.construct_node(SimpleContentHandler.java:71)
>      at SimpleContentHandler.startElement(SimpleContentHandler.java:40)

If i delete the tag that is involve in the error , the same error appear at the next tag .

Anyone know how to resolve this ?

Thanks you.

Comment: You should post the code you are using to parse this xml.

Answer (score 1):

`2151726861` is out of `Integer`'s range , Use `long` instead if you have control of parsing, if not then adjust your nodeId to allowable range of number

Comment: Thanks you i will use long because the xml is generate by openstreetmap and i can't do something with is .